# Вызов methods функции из анонимной функции в другой methods функции

Tags: vue.js

```
data: function () {

    return {

        items: {},

    }

},

methods: {

    searchPlaces: function() {

        // ................

        service.textSearch(request, function(results) {

            $.each(results, function(index, value) {                

                // ВЫЗВАТЬ pushResult

            });

        });

    }

    pushResult: function (value) {

        this.items.push(value);             

    },

    // ................
```

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как вызвать pushResult из searchPlaces.
Вызов  через this.pushResult работает, Но вызов обернут в две анонимные функции.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните уже использовать стрелочные функции и забудьте про проблему контекста вызова. Замените ваши `function` на стрелочные.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало. Стрелочные функции используют глобальный контекст.